# Value Error: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, arrays

i got this problem when i try to run this part of the code:

```
n_input = 30
n_features = 35
pred_list = []

batch = train[-n_input:].reshape((1, n_input, n_features))

for i in range(n_input):   
    pred_list.append(model.predict(batch)[0]) 
    batch = np.append(batch[:,1:,:],[[pred_list[i]]],axis=1)
```

I've tried some answers in this site, like:

- [numpy array concatenate: "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989950/numpy-array-concatenate-valueerror-all-the-input-arrays-must-have-same-number)
- [Linear regression:ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53788058/linear-regressionvalueerror-all-the-input-array-dimensions-except-for-the-conc)

No one of those helped me :(

```
Value Error: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 2, the array at index 0 has size 35 and the array at index 1 has size 1
```

This is the input:

```
Cantidad    dia month   anio    diferencia  retraso_1   retraso_2   retraso_3   retraso_4   retraso_5   retraso_6   retraso_7   retraso_8   retraso_9   retraso_10  retraso_11  retraso_12  retraso_13  retraso_14  retraso_15  retraso_16  retraso_17  retraso_18  retraso_19  retraso_20  retraso_21  retraso_22  retraso_23  retraso_24  retraso_25  retraso_26  retraso_27  retraso_28  retraso_29  retraso_30
61  0.00    5   3   2016    -26.10  -3.74   20.68   -21.52  -45.64  76.32   0.00    -9.60   -17.40  -7.67   -13.24  44.91   3.00    0.00    -25.52  12.29   -31.66  -33.83  52.47   26.25   0.00    -51.27  18.17   13.87   19.23   0.00    0.00    0.00    -12.28  -64.23  58.59
62  0.00    6   3   2016    0.00    -26.10  -3.74   20.68   -21.52  -45.64  76.32   0.00    -9.60   -17.40  -7.67   -13.24  44.91   3.00    0.00    -25.52  12.29   -31.66  -33.83  52.47   26.25   0.00    -51.27  18.17   13.87   19.23   0.00    0.00    0.00    -12.28  -64.23
63  57.20   7   3   2016    57.20   0.00    -26.10  -3.74   20.68   -21.52  -45.64  76.32   0.00    -9.60   -17.40  -7.67   -13.24  44.91   3.00    0.00    -25.52  12.29   -31.66  -33.83  52.47   26.25   0.00    -51.27  18.17   13.87   19.23   0.00    0.00    0.00    -12.28
64  34.48   8   3   2016    -22.72  57.20   0.00    -26.10  -3.74   20.68   -21.52  -45.64  76.32   0.00    -9.60   -17.40  -7.67   -13.24  44.91   3.00    0.00    -25.52  12.29   -31.66  -33.83  52.47   26.25   0.00    -51.27  18.17   13.87   19.23   0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Comment: it's hard to tell without your input, but it seems like your dimensions don't match so numpy can't concatenate

Comment: @NicolasGervais It is some way to match dimensions?